# Alter Magento 2 shipping address on request

Tags: magento2, shipping-address

I want to alter shipping on some payment method like pickup.
I found request `mine/shipping-information` and i try alter it like so:
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js`

```
           payload.addressInformation.shipping_address.firstname ='Change1';
           payload.addressInformation.billing_address.firstname ='Change2';
```

I just change name in example to easy check is it working.

In magento 2 order, I can see that billing address has change but not the shipping address.
Is there any way to alter this so I can change address ?

Comment: Store owner can configure multiple shipping address. Please follow this blog to know more. https://store.magenest.com/blog/multiple-shipping-addresses-magento-2/

Comment: I just want to change shipping address for entire order. And when I change request like in post change is send however is not reflected in order. Customer address is changed but not shipping address no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin:

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface">
    <plugin name="change_shipping_address" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ChangeShippingAddress"/>
</type>
```

> Vendor/Module/Plugin\ChangeShippingAddress.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote as QuoteEntity;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

/**
 * ChangeShippingAddress class
 */
class ChangeShippingAddress
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement
     * @param QuoteEntity $quote
     * @param array $orderData
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function beforeSubmit(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
        QuoteEntity $quote,
        $orderData = []
    ) {
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setFirstname('New Name');
        $quote->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress);

        return [$quote, $orderData];
    }
}
```

Other way you need to modify another request: `shipping-information`, but it usually dispatched before the payment method selection.

Comment: I am tring to do it in api shipping information

Comment: I have  try to do this and worked however i cant find carrierCode and base on this setShipping. I see this information in Shipping & Handling Information(admin panel) but i don`t know how to replace it to shipping

Answer (score 0):

How same can be done using observer